# Facebook access token is taking user_photos permission only for developer account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, grails, groovy

I want to get the albums from the Facebook in my app. I'm requesting the accessToken with email,user_about_me,user_photos permissions. While authenticating with the Facebook account in the pop window it is written as **"app will receive the following info: your public profile, email address, photos and personal description."**, this message is coming only for the developer account .

If I login through another account the pop up window text will be like this **"app will receive the following info: your public profile and email address. "**, there is no photos permission is coming in this message, as a result my accesstToken doesn't getting the albums of the user.

I made the app live for the public. I'm working on grails framework in groovy language

```
     private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
static def getLoginUrl() {
    def params = [
            response_type: "code",
            client_id    : CLIENT_ID,
            redirect_uri : REDIRECT_URI,
            scope        : "email,user_about_me,user_photos"
    ]
    def url = "$AUTH_URL?" + params.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }.join('&')
    return url
}
```

**EDIT:** I just now created a new app in another facebook developer account and I used those credentials in my app. Then my app is getting albums from that devloper account only. It seems that it is working with the developer account. I checked all options age is anyone(13) , country option is also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Read about "Login Review" in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Most permissions only work for users with a role in the App by default, you have to go through a review process with those.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I'll try and get back to u